# Different behaviour of Sonar for slightly two similar scenarios

Tags: java, sonarqube, pmd

Consider following case

```
public void setRules(MyRule[] rules) {
    this.rules=rules;
}
```

`Sonar` complain and says,

> Constructors and methods receiving arrays should clone objects and
>   store the copy. This prevents that future changes from the user affect
>   the internal functionality.

This is true and I got the point when some one change the value of `array` after setting this, That change may effect to inside functions. If we clone that array changes will not effect.

Now  consider another case

```
public void setExecutions(List<MyRule> ruleList) {
    this.ruleList= ruleList;
}
```

Now `Sonar` not telling any issue. why clone is not needed here?

Comment: sonar is an IDE ?? maybe its the parameter object that is acting as a clone .

Comment: @SrinathGanesh No it is an open source platform for Continuous Inspection of code quality. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SonarQube, http://www.sonarqube.org/effective-code-review-with-sonar/

Comment: this Q needs more attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact there can be only one motivation behind this PMD rule : primitives are passes by value and objects are passes by reference. What about arrays ? arrays are objects in Java and so are also passes by reference but some junior developers may not be aware of that and might believe that the whole array is passes by value. Personally I think this rule is valueless.

Comment: Both List and array are object here. Your answer is irrelevant.

Comment: That was exactly my point @Ruchira, both are objects but the goal of this rule is not to forbid passing some parameters by reference otherwise let's stop using Java. So the goal of this rule only seems to warn junior java developers that arrays (even of primitives) are passed by reference and not by value. Whereas there isn't any ambiguity when using a class from the Java collection.